# Any Problem with assigning $_POST to a variable?

Tags: php

I usually do assigning the `$_POST` superglobal to a variable something like `$post` to quickly write my code but I started thinking lately whether I am doing is good or not?

Comment: "to quickly write my code" --- are you serious? Does -1 keystroke really change something for you?

Comment: What changes is to reach `_` sign :)

Comment: At least name it `$P` or something short... Or write a post function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually write a function for this:

```
function post($key) {
   return isset($_POST[$key]) ? trim($_POST[$key]) : null;
}
```

But to answer you question, no there is nothing intrinsically wrong with this.  It just has the potential for a lack of clarity and `$_POST` is in the global scope whereas your assignment is not.

Answer (score 1):

Technically there is no any problem.

But following the general design principles - you just make not necessary action.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea, in my opinion, because it can be confusing to others in the future. Which of these is clearer?

```
echo $_POST['name'];
```

or

```
$post = $_POST;
// ... lots of code in between
echo $post['name'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it's an extra step that needs to be executed every time... if you're not working on a high-volume application it will probably not be noticeable.  I understand it's a pain in the butt to touchtype that variable name every time, but renaming it to something easier to type is not really a good programming practice.

Comment: Even on really hard loaded application the overload will be negligible

Answer (score 0):

You can assign POST/GET global key value to any variable. Just make sure to sanitize it as per your need.

If you are expecting say,

```
$employer_id = (int)$_GET['id'];
```

... so on